# Is it possible to apply rewrite first and then Deny/Apply IP block with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to apply redirect before Deny/Allow IP blocking with .htaccess file?

I tried following, but instead of redirect users that are not whitelisted were blocked so it means that Deny/Allow part was executed even they should be redirected. The redirect part is working fine as I tested it without any IP blocking. I expected that [L] flag in rewrite would "stop" the .htaccess execution before reaching the IP blocking part.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com [L,NC,R=301]

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Why I'm doing this is because I should protect access to http://www.mysite.com/blog while still showing same 404 as is shown by the site for other invalid pages. If doing IP block first I cannot show the same 404 page generated by site framework.

Am I doing something wrong or its just not possible to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a rewrite condition to check the ip address:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#always redirect blog.mysite.com to www.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com [L,NC,R=302]

#don't redirect if the accessDenied.php page is accessed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^accessDenied\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

#redirect all not whitelisted IPs
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111 [or]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^222\.222\.222\.222
RewriteRule (.*) accessDenied.php [R=302,L]

#only whitelisted IPs will use this rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If the ip matches, the second rewrite rule will not be met, so nothing will happen. But if the ip doesn't match, the user will be redirected to your 404 error page.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I try to achieve. I maybe explained the question poorly. I want to allow access to the site only to some whilsted IPs so there must be block to deny all other IPs. Before IP blocking there should be ReWrite condition to see if specific url is tried to access and in that case use rewrite and not to proceed to IP blocking. If I understand your solution correctly there is no IP blocking in place to block all other than allowed IPs.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now blog.mysite.com should be always redirected to www.mysite.com. If an other url is accessed, only the whitelisted IP will be able to see the page, all other IPs will be redirected to an error page. But I'm not able to test the code at the moment, so I'm not 100% sure that is works properly

Comment: Is there any way to get following applied to accepted IPs, I'm sorry that I didn't include those to the original question as now it comes relevant. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: @Laowai I updated my answer again. The third paragraph avoid a redirection loop (otherwise `accessDenied.php` would be redirected to itself again and again). The next paragraph redirects every access from a not whitelisted IP to `accessDenied.php`. This allows you to add as much new rewrite rules to the end of the document as you want. They will only be used if the user's IP is whitelisted.